# Active Directory authenticate against params on get

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, active-directory

I am trying to authenticate the users login against Active Directory, but I am not using the popup Active Directory box, all I am doing is passing the data through when I do the get request to the API. How would I authenticate it because all I know how to do with c# is return a string and bool.

Please help me.

Right now I'm just returning true when someone calls the function how would I go about checking the data correctly and returning a bool to match the answer it gets.

```
public class AuthController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/auth/Uname+Pword
    public bool Get(string Uname, string Pword)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: For a start it's not necessarily safe to pass the username and password as strings to the controller. That aside you should read some authentication tutorials, like this one.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-dotnet-api

What you have asked for is a solution that could have varying implications that we wouldn't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Authenticate using LDAP in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx) is keyword for you.

```
using(var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain", "mydomain\serviceAcct", "serviceAcctPass")) {
 //Username and password for authentication.
 return context.ValidateCredentials(username, password); 
}
```

Comment: As im not familar with c# where do i put that in my controller.cs

Comment: when i put it inside my get it gives me loads of errors but they cant be fixed without making classes accoriding to vs

Comment: Thank you very much works perfectly just needed to reference directory services account management

Comment: OK. But please consider GET method since the password will be displayed on URL.

Comment: we will be encripting the username, password, and access groups into a token and putting into headers this is just concept work at the moment